# Expectancy of choosing a number and then choosing another number depending on the first choice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

You randomly choose a number from this set of $n$ numbers: $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$. Let $X$ be the number you chose. Let $Y$ be a natural number that is chosen randomly uniformly (discrete) from this set: $\{1, \dots , X\}$ Calculate:

1. $\mathbb{E}[Y]$
2. $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$
3. $ \sigma(Y)$  (Standard deviation)
4. $\mathbb{P}(X+Y = 2)$

My try:

I assumed $X$ is distributed uniformly as well..

1. $E[Y] = \frac{1+X}{2} $ (We can use the fact that if $Y \sim \text{Uniform}$ then $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{a+b}{2}$
   but it is not a value it depends on $X$ .. no? I am not quite sure about it..
2. Same like 1. (maybe?) $\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \frac{(1+X)}{2}^2$
3. $\text{SD}(Y) = \sqrt{V} = \sqrt{E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2} = \sqrt{\frac{(1+X)^2}{2} - \frac{1+X}{2}}$
4. $P(X+Y=2) = P(X=1,Y=1) =  \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{n}$

I got stuck on 1,2,3 I am completely unsure how to solve them... I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchical model is $$X \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1,n), \\ Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1,X).$$  Then the law of total expectation gives us $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[(1+X)/2] = \frac{\operatorname{E}[1+X]}{2} = \frac{1 + \operatorname{E}[X]}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{1+n}{2}\right) = \frac{3+n}{4}.$$  This is because conditioned on $X$, the variable $Y \mid X$ has expectation $\frac{1+X}{2}$; then we apply the usual rules for linearity of expectation to finish the computation.  You must understand that $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ cannot be a function of $X$; it can only depend on $n$, because $X$ is itself a random variable.  Only if we condition $Y$ on the outcome of $X$ can we allow $X$ to be part of the expression for the expectation.

For the second part, we do the same thing:
$$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y^2 \mid X]].$$  But here, how do we evaluate the inner expectatin?  We simply apply the definition of expectation of a function of a discrete random variable: $$\operatorname{E}[Y^2 \mid X] = \sum_{y=1}^X y^2 \Pr[Y = y] = \frac{1}{X} \sum_{y=1}^X y^2 = \frac{X(X+1)(2X+1)}{6X} = \frac{(X+1)(2X+1)}{6}.$$  Then proceed as usual:  $$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{(X+1)(2X+1)}{6}\right] = \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}{3} + \frac{\operatorname{E}[X]}{2} + \frac{1}{6},$$ and we evaluate $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ using the same sum of consecutive squares identity we used earlier.

For the third part, we calculate the variance $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2$$ from the previous parts, then take the square root to obtain the standard deviation.

---

It is a worthwhile exercise to consider what the marginal distribution of $Y$ actually is.  That is to say, what is $\Pr[Y = y]$, for each $y \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$?  To find this, we employ the law of total probability: note $$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=1}^n \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x]\Pr[X = x].$$  But if $x < y$, it is impossible to observe $Y = y$, so the above sum becomes $$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=y}^n \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x]\Pr[X = x] = \sum_{x=y}^n \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{H_n - H_{y-1}}{n},$$ where $$H_m = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}$$ is the $m^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.  So for example, for $n = 9$, we have the table
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
y & \Pr[Y = y] \\
\hline
 1 & \frac{7129}{22680} \\
 2 & \frac{4609}{22680} \\
 3 & \frac{3349}{22680} \\
 4 & \frac{2509}{22680} \\
 5 & \frac{1879}{22680} \\
 6 & \frac{275}{4536} \\
 7 & \frac{191}{4536} \\
 8 & \frac{17}{648} \\
 9 & \frac{1}{81} \\
\end{array}$$
and you can check that the sum of the probabilities equals $1$.  Notice how this result is rather complicated, and would make computing the marginal moments through direct calculation rather difficult, which illustrates the power of the law of total expectation.

Comment: What an awesome answer, wow! I can't thank you enough! One little question, is $E[X^2] = 1^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + 2^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + \dots = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2$ ? And about question number (4) am I right? ($ P(X+Y=1) =  \frac{1}{n}$ ) Thank you so much !!

Comment: @OnAndOff You are most welcome; the answer is yes to both of your questions.